# Bash reads text file line by line and triggers logger to log the line into var/log

Tags: bash, shell, file, ubuntu, terminal

I'd like to write a bash/bash script that could contain while loop which would read a text file line by line from the start till the end and trigger logger to make a log file from the current line.

Does anyone have any ideas how to achieve that?

Code:

```
#!/bin/bash

# A shell script to read file line by line
filename="/home/user/logs.txt" 

while read line do
    # $line variable contains current line read from the file 
    # display $line text on the screen or do something with it.
    logger "$line"
done < $filename
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? Which logger are you talking about?

Comment: #!/bin/bash
# A shell script to read file line by line
 
filename="/home/user/logs.txt"
 
while read line
do
    # $line variable contains current line read from the file
    # display $line text on the screen or do something with it.
 
    logger  "$line"
done < $filename

I'm talking about logger command on Ubuntu...

Comment: I've added the code in your question for now, but the next time you shouldn't place that in the comments. Not only is that harder to read, nobody is going to look for it there ;-)

Answer (score 1):

The [`logger`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/logger) command prints data in `/dev/log`. `logger` has a `-f` option to put the entire file into syslog.

Read a file into syslog:

```sh
$ logger -f some_file.txt
```

If you want to create X log files, each with a single line that originate from some 'parent log file', you should instead use `echo` to echo the `$line` into some file.

```sh
#! /bin/bash

filename=some_file.txt
[[ -f ${filename} ]] || exit 1
x=0
while read -r line; do
    echo $line > log$((x++)).log
done < $filename
exit 0
```

Comment: `prints data in /var/log/syslog` - this is not true. `logger` never touches /var/log/syslog. `logger` tries many log outputs, but most probably on most linux systems it writes the data to `/dev/log`.

Comment: No it doesn't. Your system logger daemon prints the data to /var/log/syslog after receiving them from logger.

Comment: You're correct; `strings $(which logger)` indeed shows `/dev/log`.

Comment: `strings` is not the tool to test it. You can create a library with all kinds of strings and they can be unused. `strace logger` will show `connect(...."/dev/log")`

Comment: Thanks for editing the script. So where can I find the logs? I cannot see them in /var/log/syslog...

Comment: I missed ‘>’ between ‘$line’ and the name of the log. Try it again :-)